# Why does python keep going after an if statement

Tags: python

```py
def whichIsLarger(x,y):
    if x > y:
        print(x, "is greater than ", y)
    if y > x:
        print(y, "is greater than ", x)
    else:
        print("These numbers are the same!")

whichIsLarger(7, 3)
```

I have the following code block. If i call whichIsLarger(7,3), it returns:
7 is greater than  3
These numbers are the same!

If i call whichIsLarger(3,7), it returns:
7 is greater than  3.

Why does the else statement get printed in one call and not the other?

Ran this through an environment diagram and it skips the else statement when the y>x statement is satisfied, but runs through the else statement when the x>y statement is satisfied. This doesn't make sense to me!!

Comment: I'm aware that changing the second if statement to elif solves this issue, but I'm wondering what the logic is behind this.

Comment: You have *two different `if` statements here*. You wanted `elif` not a second `if`

Comment: Based on your expectations - what would the difference between `if y > x` and `elif y > x` be?

Comment: You're confused because of poor code formatting. There should be space (an empty line) after the first print. That's because the first `if` and second `if` are completely unrelated. Python is not confused but our human brain get confused by such things. As such proper formatting would avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Your second `if` should be `elif`. Otherwise it's treated as a new if-statement.

You have effectively written this code right now:

```
    if x > y:
        print(x, "is greater than ", y)
    else:
        pass

    if y > x:
        print(y, "is greater than ", x)
    else:
        print("These numbers are the same!")
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `if, elif, else`

```
def whichIsLarger(x,y):
    if x > y:
        print(x, "is greater than ", y)
    elif y > x:
        print(y, "is greater than ", x)
    else:
        print("These numbers are the same!")


whichIsLarger(7, 3)
```

If you keep 2 `if`s then it will skip one `if` and `else` will be executed in both the cases.

*For multiple ifs code would go and check all the if conditions, where as in case of elif, if one if condition satisfies it would not check other conditions*

Answer (score 0):

If the condition for an if statement *is not* met, it will continue on down to the next line that is indented in the same place as that if statement.

If the condition *is* met, it will run the indented code below it. After that it will go to the next line.

To answer your question about why the else is running even though x>y condition was satisfied, in your example, it checks if the x>y, yes it is so it prints x is greater than y. Next, it checks if x<y, and it is not so it moves on to the else and executes that.

For x<y, the first if statement is not met, so we move on to the next if statement. It says y is greater than x, so the else will not apply. **Think of else as "otherwise".**

We can think of it like this:
if apples are better than oranges,
print apples are better than oranges.
if oranges are better than apples,
print oranges are better than apples.
otherwise oranges and apples are liked the same.

I hope this helps :)